# Error: Component definition is missing display name

Tags: reactjs, react-table

i have following code using react-table hook. Vercel compilation shows the following error msg:
***49:15  Error: Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name*** where the Line 49 indicated in the code below.

```
const tableHooks = (hooks) => {
    hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => [
      ...columns,
      {
        accessor: "status",
        Header: "Status",
        Cell: ({ row }) => (  // Line 49
          <h6
            className={classes.editstatus}
            onClick={() => bookingDetailHandler(row.original.brewery_type)}
            value={row.original.brewery_type}
          >
            {row.original.brewery_type}
          </h6>
        ),
      },
    ]);
  };
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    page,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
    setPageSize,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    canNextPage,
    canPreviousPage,
    pageOptions,
    // state,
    gotoPage,
    pageCount,
    prepareRow,
    flatRows,
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      // defaultColumn
    },
    tableHooks,
    // useFilters,
    useSortBy,
    usePagination
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just switch arrow function to a named function

```
{
    accessor: "status",
    Header: "Status",
    Cell: function statusItems({ row }) {
      return (
        <h6
            className={classes.editstatus}
            onClick={() => bookingDetailHandler(row.original.brewery_type)}
            value={row.original.brewery_type}
          >
            {row.original.brewery_type}
          </h6>
      );
    },
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Vitally for your time. After change it to named function, how do I declare the  statusItems in the ReactTable instance?

Comment: `statusItems` is custom function, you don't need to declare it in ReactTable instance

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy. your suggestion helps